# How to create a voronoi texture with different color in every tile and black lines in between?

Tags: texturing

The image below shows a simple cube with the following node setup:
[image]

[image]

is there a way to input different colors instead of just the color blue?

The idea is to have an output of something like this:
[image]

Comment: Change the color ramp node. Click on a slider, or add one and choose the color you want. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/color_ramp.html?highlight=color%20ramp#color-ramp-node

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that reflects the content of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make all the tiles different color you could just take the color output of the voronoi texture and play with that. It's already quite close to what you want. If you want the black lines you need to add more nodes to mix it with.

[image: Multicolor Voronoi]

### Update

Here are two different results. This one has uniform lines and the last one has little distortion added so it closer to the original picture.

[image: Uniform lines]

[image: Distortion]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I apologize for not making my question clear enough. to be specific, I wanted to have blue, red, gray, yellow color on the same face.

Comment: PERFECT! You're a lifesaver! Thank you brother!

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer is good enough you can accept it with the check mark next to the answer.